# How to make floor like this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

How can I make reflecting floor like this in blender?
And how do I make good looking glass like the one provided in the example too? 
Edit: I wanna make a nice reflective floor like the one provided in the image. And I wanna know how to make glass like the glass cubes in the provided example.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9w0l.jpg)

Comment: Please read: [what is the problem with posting an image or a link and aksing how do I do this?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: @nicola sap nope

Comment: @cegaton fixed it

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and **use the tools from this site 
to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question**. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Speaking, create a plain and add a material to it.

Selecting that material go to node editor, and make it something like this instead, instead of plain.. and also use some texture with normal maps and play with color ramp to make it look realistic.

In this case i've used noise texture. but use can use anyother textures (i.e voronoi texture, musgrave texture, wave texture). or even mix two or even three or even four textures and try experimenting.

[image: Something Like This]

I've set a plain texture for my plane and gave my sun "blue" color so it turn out like this. But you can see the reflections same as puddle of water in the pic you've put the link. I mean the shape and the roughness.

[image: output like this]

Comment: And how do i make glass cubes like that in the image?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Use same material as this i.stack.imgur.com/VTPpj.png but also add in glass shader (or) translucent shader in it and use mix shader.

Comment: My friend made a scene which you've linked in your question, containing a plain and a cube with ice textures in blender 2.8+

Blender files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UhdAXO_xR_PxoZO-LaasaXTZfMCm4Duu